# Docker CMD weirdness when ENTRYPOINT is a shell script

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Here's a simple Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:6.6
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c"]
CMD ["echo", "foo"]
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Nothing is echo'd when you run the resulting container that's built.
If you comment out the `ENTRYPOINT` then it works. However, if you set the `ENTRYPOINT` to `/bin/sh -c`, then it fails again

```
FROM centos:6.6
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
CMD ["echo", "foo"]
```

I thought that was the default `ENTRYPOINT` for an container that didn't have one defined, why didn't that work?

Finally, this also works

```
FROM centos:6.6
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c"]
CMD ["echo foo"]
```

Before I submit an issue, I wanted to see if I'm doing something obviously wrong?
I'm using `rvm` inside my container which sort of needs a login shell to work right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the [default entry point/cmd for an official centos 6 image](https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-images/blob/20732d1bb34a9aba45c1c6f41576ed6bf3d8c619/docker/Dockerfile#L8) is:

- no entrypoint
- only `CMD ["/bin/bash"]`

If you are using the `-c` command, you need to pass *one* argument (which is the full command): `"echo foo"`.
Not a series of arguments (`CMD ["echo", "foo"]`).

As stated in [dockerfile CMD](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#cmd) section:

> If you use the shell form of the CMD, then the `<command>` will execute in `/bin/sh -c`:

```
FROM ubuntu
CMD echo "This is a test." | wc -
```

> If you want to run your `<command>` without a shell then you must express the command as a JSON array and give the full path to the executable

**[Since `echo` is a built-in command in the bash and C shells](http://www.linfo.org/echo.html), the shell form here is preferable.**

Comment: Yeah, so I think the bottom line is that if you're setting ENTRYPOINT to be bash -c CMD needs to be a single argument, not a json array as the array will only pass the FIRST element to the command to run. That makes sense even if the documentation seems confusing about that.