# "CMD ['/home/user/script.sh']" in docker file doesn't work with docker-compose

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

I have a Docker file, thats builds perfectly with: `docker build -t myfile .`
But when I trying to run it with **docker-compose** - it gives me an error:

```
web_1 | /bin/sh: 1: [/home/root/myproject/uwsgi.sh: not found
myproject_web_1 exited with code 127
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
```

If I start this script manually - it works fine.

**Dockerfile** looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

ADD ./myproject/ /home/root/myproject/

WORKDIR /home/root/myproject/

# Some other stuff...

CMD ['/home/root/myproject/uwsgi.sh', 'start' ]
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
web:
  build: .
  ports:
   - "8888:8888"
  links:
   - db
db:
  image: mysql
```

Why I getting this error? 
Thank you.

Comment: Are you using .dockerignore? https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2109#issuecomment-144163891

Comment: well if it says uwsgi.sh not found I'd first use a bash and look whether it's there and with what ownership and permissions ...

Comment: If you built it in on a windows host run dos2unix on it after the ADD or COPY

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I simplified your example a bit

see https://github.com/BITPlan/docker-stackoverflowanswers/tree/master/33229581

and used:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
web:
  build: .
  ports:
   - "8888:8888"
```

**find .**

```
.
./docker-compose.yml
./Dockerfile
./myproject
```

**docker build & run**

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose run web
```

and of course I get

```
/bin/sh: 1: [/home/root/myproject/uwsgi.sh,: not found
```

assuming this is since there is no uwsgi.sh in the directory myproject.

If I add uwsgi.sh with

```
echo 'echo $0 is there and called with params $@!' > myproject/uwsgi.sh
chmod +x myproject/uwsgi.sh
```

and test it with

```
docker-compose run web /bin/bash
ls
cat uwsgi.sh
./uwsgi.sh start
```

it's there and behaves as expected:

```
root@9f06f8ff8c3b:/home/root/myproject# ls
uwsgi.sh
root@9f06f8ff8c3b:/home/root/myproject# cat uwsgi.sh 
echo $0 is there and called with params $@!
root@9f06f8ff8c3b:/home/root/myproject# ./uwsgi.sh start
./uwsgi.sh is there and called with params start!
 root@9f06f8ff8c3b:/home/root/myproject#
```

but for docker-compose run web I still get

```
/bin/sh: 1: [/home/root/myproject/uwsgi.sh,: not found
```

If I add a single blank to the Dockerfile CMD line:

```
CMD [ '/home/root/myproject/uwsgi.sh', 'start' ]
```

the result is:
    /bin/sh: 1: [: /home/root/myproject/uwsgi.sh,: unexpected operator

which brings us closer. As a next step I am leaving out the "start" parameter.

```
CMD [ '/home/root/myproject/uwsgi.sh' ]
```

this now leads to no output at all ...

If i change the CMD line to:

```
CMD [ "/home/root/myproject/uwsgi.sh", "start" ]
```

I get

```
 Cannot start container 
 0b9da138c43ef308ad70da4a7718cb96fbfdf6cda113e2ae0ce5e24de06f07cd: [8]  
 System   error: exec format error
```

and now you could continue in the Edison like approach:

***I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.***
until you find

```
CMD [ "/bin/bash", "/home/root/myproject/uwsgi.sh", "start" ]
```

which brings you closer with the result:

```
 /home/root/myproject/uwsgi.sh is there and called with params start!
```

CMD expects an executable as the first parameter e.g.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/

has

```
CMD python app.py
```

as an example. To run your shell script you'll need a shell like bash.
See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/33219131/1497139

Answer (score 4):

For others out there looking for help with this error message: I found that in my case it was caused by commas missing from the CMD line. The error state:

```
$ grep ^CMD Dockerfile
CMD ["/bin/sh" "-c" "hostname"]
$ docker run --rm -it hostname
/bin/sh: 1: [/bin/sh: not found
```

Putting the commas in correctly like so fixed the problem:

```
$ grep ^CMD Dockerfile
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "hostname"]
```